# Finding the closest date, that is most recent date - 1 year's value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, vlookup

I have the following table, `table1`:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 05/04/2022 | 400 |
| 22/04/2022 | 312 |
| 04/05/2022 | 942 |
| 06/08/2022 | 231 |
| 12/08/2022 | 243 |

I want to get the most recent **date** in the table (in this case `12/08/2022`) and minus 1 year from it to get `12/08/2021`. Then look at the table to find the **value** that is most closest to `12/08/2021`. In this case, the closest value is from the table is `05/04/2022`, so the formula will return  `400`.

I tried with this formula, but really unclear how to do it.

```
=VLOOKUP(IFERROR(MAX(Table1[date])-365,MAX(Table1[date])), Table1, 2,TRUE)
```

I have Microsoft Excel 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```vb
=LET(mostRecentDate,MAX(table1[date]),
     previousYearDate,mostRecentDate-365,
     MIN(FILTER(table1[date],table1[date]>previousYearDate))
     )
```

If you don't have the `FILTER`-function try this:

```
=INDEX(table1[date],MATCH(MIN(ABS(table1[date]-(MAX(table1[date])-365))),ABS(table1[date]-(MAX(table1[date])-365)),0))
```

It checks for the differences to the max-date - 365

Comment: I unfortunately dont. I just have microsoft 2020

Comment: maybe that works as well - try if you get the FILTER by typing `= FI` into one cell

Comment: added a non Excel-365-formula